# One way of rxjava subscribe hangs and one doesn't, why?

Tags: rx-java

I have a particular observable chain that hangs on me. After some research I found out that replacing subscribe(subscriber) with a variant with onNext fixes the problem. The only difference between the two is that in the hanging variant my subscriber is wrapped into a SafeSubscriber which unsubscribes in onCompleted. Nonetheless, I don't understand why it hangs. Can someone explain this to me or point me somewhere?

This code hangs:

```
Scheduler sch = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

Observable
    .create(subscriber -> Observable.just(null).subscribe(subscriber))
    .flatMap(ignored -> Observable.just(null).observeOn(sch))
    .toBlocking()
    .first();
```

This doesn't:

```
Scheduler sch = Schedulers.from(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

Observable
    .create(subscriber -> Observable.just(null).subscribe(value -> subscriber.onNext(value)))
    .flatMap(ignored -> Observable.just(null).observeOn(sch))
    .toBlocking()
    .first();
```

The construct may seem strange but please note that I tried to simplify it to the shortest possible example that reproduces the problem. In reality it's much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `subscriber -> Observable.just(null).subscribe(subscriber)`.
Never reuse a `subscriber` because it's stateful. The `Subscriber` passed to `Observable.onSubscribe` has already been `subscribe`d. Don't call `subscribe` on it again. If you find you need to call `subscribe` in `Observable.onSubscribe`, you should consider using `lift`.